# Want to customize [the_excerpt] length form wp

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to customize the excerpt length on posts. I'm using this function on `function.php`:

```
function get_excerpt(){
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" ([.*?])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 25);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.$permalink.'">[...]</a>';

    return $excerpt;
}
```

and using it on this tag

```
<article class="secundary">
    <div class="mini">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
    </div>

    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p>por <span><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> em <span><?php the_category(' '); ?></span> <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', '); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
    <p><?php get_excerpt(); ?></p>
</article>
```

Anyone could help me? It didn't work… why?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write a custom function for changing the excerpt length.

You can use the `excerpt_length` filter. You can use following code in your functions.php file.

```
function mytheme_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
   return 25;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'mytheme_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

And then just use the default `the_excerpt()` tag in your post template.

This will display post excerpt of 25 characters. For more option to customize excerpt check the following link.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid limiting by characters as that delivers a performance hit.  Instead, limit by words.  Put the following in your functions.php:

```
function excerpt($limit) {
  $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}
```

Wherever you use the excerpt in your template files, you can now add the amount of words you would like displayed (for example, 30) as follows:

```
echo excerpt(30)
```